# WPF Highlight duplicate items in a Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, listbox

I'd like to highlight list items that are equal to each other. In this example case I have a person object with a name and age, if that persons in their twice, i'd like both instances of it to be highlighted.

There is an ObservableCollection, People which contains a list of Person objects.

XAML side

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock>Name</TextBlock>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding CurrentPerson, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
    <Button Command="{Binding AddPersonDelegateCommand}">Add</Button>
    <Button>Remove</Button>
    <ListBox x:Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding People}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}">

    </ListBox>
    <TextBox Name="txtName" Text="{Binding SelectedPerson.Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"</TextBox>
    <TextBox Name="txtAge" Text="{Binding SelectedPerson.Age, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

How can I do this efficiently?

I considered doing it with a ItemContainerStyle, but bindings there seem to refer to the DataContext and not the listboxitem itself.

another method i thought i could use is a datatemplate with a textbox, bind to the background with a converter and multiple bindings (was going to use params but they arent bindable) and if a duplicate is found, send Red back. In this case i'd need to find two duplicates since it will come across itself, or do a reference compare on a value equality. The problem I have with this method is being able to access the collection itself (opposite issue with the last idea)

The other thought was to have it all on the code side and make a property IsDup or something like that, but I again run in to a similar issue because when the Name or Age value changes, from that instance of the Person i'd have to look at the People collection, which I dont have a way of getting.

I realize this is getting voted down (comments would be nice as to why) but i assume its because i didnt provide what i've tired,  the problem is I cant say i've tried anything because in all the methods I've thought of, i've hit road blocks that make it impossible (for me) to move forward. I thought rather than listing the ways that didnt work (and possibly couldnt work) I thought i'd just ask what the best way to approach this is.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put an Event on the objects in the Observable collection so it triggered any time an important property was changed.

The event was registered on the viewmodel and the following method was run to figure out if it was a dup or not.

```
 public void TagDup(ProductConnection selectedProductConnection)
    {
        selectedProductConnection.IsDup = false;

        //check to see if the 'current' item is a dup with anything in the list
        ProductConnections.Where(o => !ReferenceEquals(o, selectedProductConnection) && o.GetDupHash() == selectedProductConnection.GetDupHash()).ToList().ForEach(o => o.IsDup = selectedProductConnection.IsDup = true);
        //look for orphaned dup tags
        var grp = ProductConnections.Where(o => o.IsDup).GroupBy(o => o.GetDupHash()).Where(o => o.Count() == 1).ToList();
        ProductConnections.Where(x => grp.Select(a => a.Key).Contains(x.GetDupHash())).ToList().ForEach(o => o.IsDup = false);
    }
```

And then on the XAML side I used ItemContainerStyle and a Converter

```
 <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
     <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding IsDup, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToColor}}"></Setter>
     </Style>
 </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

I avoided the use of IsSelected because selections are used in other areas, I hadnt proved it would present a problem, but it seemed like it probably would.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right path with the `ItemContainerStyle`.  Hopefully you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on `Person` so that selecting a `Person` notifies the UI.  Anyways, check out this short code sample, it's rather self-explanatory:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding People}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Header"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected"
                    Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Person _selectedPerson;
    public Person SelectedPerson
    {
        get
        {
            return this._selectedPerson;
        }
        set
        {
            this._selectedPerson = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedPerson");
        }
    }


    ObservableCollection<Person> _people = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    public ObservableCollection<Person> People
    {
        get
        {
            return this._people;
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        var guy = new Person("Me");
        this.People.Add(guy);      // <---- ADDED GUY ONCE
        this.People.Add(new Person("You"));
        this.People.Add(new Person("Us"));
        this.People.Add(guy);     // <----- SAME GUY ADDED
        this.SelectedPerson = this.People[0];

        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

Person.cs

```
public class Person : ViewModel
{
    public string Header { get; set; }

    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return _isSelected;
        }
        set
        {
            _isSelected = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }
    public Person(string n)
    {
        Header = n;
    }
}
```

ViewModel.cs

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Output, and view after selecting the first "Me" in the `ListBox`.

[image: Output]

Bonus Snippet, change the control template and you change what the item + selected item's look like:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding People}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Header"
            SelectionMode="Multiple"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected"
                    Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Border x:Name="Bd"
                                Width="100"
                                Height="40"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Background="Orange"
                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                                Margin="0 2">
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
                                <Path x:Name="checkmark"
                                        Width="11"
                                        Height="11"
                                        Margin="0 5 5 0"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="False"
                                        Stroke="Black"
                                        StrokeThickness="2"
                                        Data="M 2,4 C 2,4 3,5 5,13 C 5,13 5,3 12,0"
                                        Visibility="Hidden" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                                        Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility"
                                        TargetName="checkmark"
                                        Value="Visible" />
                                <Setter Property="Background"
                                        TargetName="Bd"
                                        Value="Green" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                                                Value="True" />
                                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive"
                                                Value="False" />
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background"
                                        TargetName="Bd"
                                        Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                        Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}}" />
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                                        Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                        Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Output with Bonus XAML:

[image]

Comment: That works because you're referencing the same object (set IsSelected on one, and its set on the other because its a reference). What im looking to capture is if someone enter the same name twice, which would make it two differnt objects with the same values. So in order to know if it was duplicated I'd have to search for it (value wise) in the collection. If i come up with two copies (one will be itself) and the other will be the duplicate based on value. what you'll have to do is People.Add(new Person("Me"));People.Add(new Person("Me")); creating two different objects with the same values

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to make it two different objects... It doesn't become a second object until the object is created.  If someone enters the same name and they click "Add", and someone by that name already exists, then take that Person already in the list and add them again.

Comment: You're still going to want to follow about 80% of this code.  If you don't want it referencing the same person (therefore not equal if you think about it), then after you add the person to the list, you will need to run a `SelectedDuplicates` function which searches the collection and does a `.Select( x => x.IsSelected = true )` when matches occur.

Comment: The main point being that you're setting `IsSelected = true` will automatically selection items in the list box.  You could call `People.Select( x => x.IsSelected = true );` and all the items would show up as selected.  How you determine duplicates is a different matter.

Comment: That makes sense, let me screw around with this and see if i can make it work. Thanks!

Comment: Ok so the problem I have here is if the object is modified, how do i trigger the search of the list? from the Person i dont have access to People, and from the VM i dont have the ability to monitor for changes (unless i register for events on the Person from the VM)

Comment: That sounds like a separate question in itself.  You could pass reference of the AddressBookVM to the Person, or implement an explicit interface on the AddressBookVM and hold reference the the interface in the Person.  You could also hook into NotifyPropertyChanged for each person on the AddreessBookVM.  Those are a couple of ways.